# Problem connecting to spark in rstudio with sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark

I am trying to establish a connection to spark via Rstudio using sparklyr package, but is giving me this error:

```
  Failed while connecting to sparklyr to port (8880) for sessionid (40729): Gateway in localhost:8880 did not respond.
    Path: C:\spark\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\spark-submit2.cmd
    Parameters: --driver-memory, 2g, --class, sparklyr.Shell, "C:\Users\Juan Ossa\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\sparklyr\java\sparklyr-2.0-2.11.jar", 8880, 40729
    Log: C:\Users\JUANOS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpG6SLIz\file40b461315f3b_spark.log


---- Output Log ----
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

---- Error Log ----
```

I already try to increase the max heapsize using:

```
config[["sparklyr.shell.conf"]] <- "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:MaxHeapSize=4g"
```

but the error still appears

This is my actual code:

```
config <- spark_config()
config[["sparklyr.shell.conf"]] <- "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:MaxHeapSize=4g"
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
```

I put here some sessioninfo() if help some way and I have a CPU with 12GB of RAM:

```
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Argentina.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Argentina.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Argentina.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Spanish_Argentina.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sparklyr_1.0.9005
```